# Potential Limitations to using getString() insted of getClob() for PostgreSQL database

Tags: java, postgresql, prepared-statement

I am currently working with a product which has either a PostgreSQL database or an Oracle database

In this application, there is a `getClob()` which will return a clob from an oracle database. However this becomes a problem when the application is using a PostgreSQL database, as the `getClob()` produces errors, but `getString()` works perfectly

My question is then: will there be any limitations if I use `getString()` insted of using `getClob()`? Limitations such as getString can only handle half the data a clob can etc

Any Help would be appriciated :)

Comment: Well as you said, you can't use `getClob()` so the question doesn't really make sense as you don't have a choice here. But `getString()` works perfectly fine with any `varchar` or `text` column in Postgres.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name there is implementations for getClob on postgresql, its just that with the way my code is set up, it tries to format some string into a long? Which confuses me. So you say that it would be fine to use getstring on both oracle and postgresql, no limitations?

Comment: Yes, in my experience `getString()` works just fine on both DBMS (including CLOB columns in Oracle - at least with any JDBC driver after 10g)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name thank you for the clarification :)  just needed to check